# convert data frame to list of list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have below data frame

```
POC_Number  Resource_Number day_to_complete_task
0   0   12
0   1   12
0   5   6
1   3   8
1   0   7
1   5   5
2   3   9
2   2   11
2   4   10
```

and want output as below list of lists :

`[[(0, 12), (1, 12), (5, 6)], [(3, 8), (0, 7), (5, 5)], [(3, 9),(2, 11), (4, 10)]]`

Comment: before you ask post the code you have tried and then expect for help

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
df.groupby('POC_Number').apply(lambda x: [tuple(i[1:]) for i in x.values]).to_list()
```

or:

```
df.groupby('POC_Number')['Resource_Number', 'day_to_complete_task'].apply(
    lambda x: [tuple(i) for i in  x.values]).to_list()
```

output:

```
[[(0, 12), (1, 12), (5, 6)],
 [(3, 8), (0, 7), (5, 5)],
 [(3, 9), (2, 11), (4, 10)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
result = df.groupby('POC_Number')[['Resource_Number', 'day_to_complete_task']].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
result = [list(map(tuple, i)) for i in list(result)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[(0, 12), (1, 12), (5, 6)], [(3, 8), (0, 7), (5, 5)], [(3, 9), (2, 11), (4, 10)]]
```